# Router outlet not working in custom component

Tags: angular

I just started developing a new Angular application. It needs a header and footer that appears on every page so I went ahead and created 3 components: layout, header and footer.

I then went ahead and changed my `app.component.html` to `<app-layout></app-layout>`

The layout component itself is as follows:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

and

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-layout',
  templateUrl: './layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./layout.component.scss']
})
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

It all worked until I went ahead and changed `<ng-content>` to `<router-outlet>`. The header and footer files just contain some text as a placeholder, nothing special there. But the header and footer disappeared as well when I changed that one line.

Comment: `the header and footer disappeared as well when I changed that one line`. Are you sure you don't have any error in the console?

Comment: Absolutely no errors in the console. And this is a brand new app.

Comment: the header and footer disappeared, but does the router-outlet work fine?

Comment: Tbh, I think you have some error in console but you just don't see it. Did you import RouterModule? Did you provide a routing module?

Comment: @CristianTraìna - https://imgur.com/a/yWvqIpn Please show me the errors....

Comment: In console, not in the terminal. These are just the compilation errors, I'm talking about runtime errors. So open the page and press `F12` (on chrome) and you'll see something

Comment: Apologies - I found that the RouterModule was missing. Thanks!

Comment: was the first version of your code like this ?

`<ng-content select="router-outlet"></ng-content>`